# How to update an object without vanishing existing values in java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, spring-data-jpa

I receive an XML in the API request and it will be converted to an Object and it will be saved into database (MSSQL). I may receive an update of the same Object with some added fields.
In this case how to update all the attributes that I receive in the new request without vanishing the existing value. Currently, I am manually comparing the old and new object and setting up the new value using setters.
**Is there a library or some better methods that I can make use of to handle this without pain?**

```
Ex:
 Class Person {
    
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Date tStamp;
    private String phone;
    
    private Address address; 
    private List<EmploymentHistory> job;
    
 }
```

Assume if I get firstName and lastName in the first request and phone and address and Job in the subsequent request.
currently I am doing something like below. it is depicted for one of the attributes in the object graph. but actual object graph can go to many level.

```
if(personOld.getlastName() == null && personNew.getlastName != null) 
    personNew.setlastName("XX");
```

Any help on this would be really appreciated. TIA!

Comment: @GhostCat have updated with better names. I am using Spring boot + MSSQL and XML is the input data format.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking to use [Reflect](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html). Reflect allows you to iterate thought methods and attributes of an object. This way you can create a function that does what you want for any object you want.

Also, in Spring you can extend BeanUtils to achive that:

```
public class ObjectUtils extends BeanUtils {

    public static String[] getNullPropertyNames (Object source) {
        final BeanWrapper src = new BeanWrapperImpl(source);
        java.beans.PropertyDescriptor[] pds = src.getPropertyDescriptors();

        Set<String> emptyNames = new HashSet<String>();
        for(java.beans.PropertyDescriptor pd : pds) {
            Object srcValue = src.getPropertyValue(pd.getName());
            if (srcValue == null) emptyNames.add(pd.getName());
        }

        String[] result = new String[emptyNames.size()];
        return emptyNames.toArray(result);
    }

    public static void copyProperties(Object src, Object target) {
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(src, target, getNullPropertyNames(src));
    }
}
```

The function `copyProperties` copies all the new values from src into target. For example if I have 2 objects:

```
target = { a: null, b: 1, c: 2}
src = { a: 2, b: null, c: 3}
```

The result would be:

```
target = { a:2, b: 1, c: 3}
```